# Scaling Kafka Consumer in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, multiprocessing

I have developed a Kafka consumer in python using python-kafka library in my local machine.My requirement is to read from 100+ topics. I have used multiprocessing module to create pool of workers for reading topics and writing to database.

I have a EC2 instance and I need to know best way to scale my application ??

Like read topics in parallel...

Comment: If you are using same consumer group, the partitions will be automatically distributed across all consumers.